# which test card number is used in India by stripe?

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe payment integration with my android app, but when I test the card it gives invalid card message means the card is null.
stripe gives these international cards in which India is not mentioned.
how I test card in India.

I tried various cards including 4242 4242 4242 4242
and also others. stripe testing cards

https://stripe.com/docs/testing#international-cards

```
 final Card cardToSave = mCardMultilineWidget.getCard();

 if (cardToSave == null) {
//     mErrorDialogHandler.showError("Invalid Card Data");

      Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Invalid Card Data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
      return ;
  }
  else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"valid Card Data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                    stripe.createToken(
                            cardToSave,
                            new TokenCallback() {
                                public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                                    //Send token to your own web service
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),token +"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }
                                public void onError(Exception error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                            error.getLocalizedMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                    );

                }
```

I want that card is valid and token return by stripe.

Comment: and what is the problem with `4242 4242 4242 4242` card?

Comment: it gives invalid card

Comment: And hint: please carefully review your question in the preview section before posting it. You want other people to spend their time to help with your problem, so you should spend the 1 minute it takes to properly format / indent your input. Plus: dont invent your own formatting. That edit window has a whole help section for you explaining how to properly format your input.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: And what makes you think that 4242 4242... represents a valid card? Shouldnt you try a VALID card first, if you want the result to be VALID?

Comment: do you use the test mode? Only in test mode test cards will work

Comment: yes I use test mode @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: Its my first time to ask question on stack so I improve it @GhostCat

Comment: On stripe page they written that Each test card's billing country is set to U.S. If you need to create test card payments using cards for other billing countries, use our international test cards.   but international test card not mention India @GhostCat

Comment: 4242 4242 4242 4242 and CVV - 123 it's working.

Comment: issue resolved , actually problem in my coding style

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: `4000003560000008`

For more numbers or other details check https://stripe.com/docs/testing#international-cards

Note: High chances to oversee the tabs on the section top, limiting to this question, you may want to check for "**Asia-Pacific**" tab

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe`s default payment card is as said 4242 4242 4242 4242 with a not passed date as expiry and 3 random numbers as CVV. F.ex i could fill 4242 4242 4242 4242 as card number, and 09/21 as expiry and 123 as CVV.

**But,**
What may be your problem is that Stripe is currently not publicly available in India as it is in invite only at the moment. Check https://stripe.com/global